# Foreach loop returns an error message for first set of workers only

Tags: r, parallel.foreach, doparallel

Something very strange started happening in a package I have been working on. I am using a foreach loop with a doparallel backend to perform repeated random walks with restarts on an adjacency matrix (reproducible example below).

```
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("foreach")
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/DavisWeaver/crosstalkr")
```

```
library(foreach)
```

```
m <- replicate(1000, sample(x = c(0,1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
w <- Matrix::Matrix(m, sparse = TRUE)
w <- Matrix::t(Matrix::t(w)/Matrix::colSums(w)) #normalize based on the column sum.
seeds <- sample(1:nrow(w), size = 32)
```

Each iteration should perform a random walk with restarts and return a numeric vector of affinity scores (so matrix in, one dimensional vector out). I tried to reproduce this error with a simpler task in each iteration but I wasn't able to. This setup worked fine for matrix::colSums(w) and several more trivial tasks.

The following error is returned for each of the first set of workers: "<simpleError in numeric(n): invalid 'length' argument>". Each subsequent iteration performs completely as expected with no errors. So when you run the first foreach loop below, you get [the following image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht0Ip.png)

When you run subseqent foreach loops using the same parallel backend, each iteration performs as expected and [there are no error messages!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjXha.png)

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

n = 8
null_dist <-
  foreach::foreach(i = 1:n, .errorhandling = 'pass') %dopar% {
    crosstalkr::sparseRWR(w, seed_proteins = seeds, norm = FALSE)[[1]]
  }

null_dist <-
  foreach::foreach(i = 1:n, .errorhandling = 'pass') %dopar% {
    crosstalkr::sparseRWR(w, seed_proteins = seeds, norm = FALSE)[[1]]
  }


parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

I am not sure where to go from here... I'm guessing it is something to do with how I am setting up the parallel backend? any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening. However, to solve the problem you need to explicitly add `.packages = "Matrix"` to `foreach`.

Without specifying `.packages`, `nrow` doesn't produce the correct results.

Here is a simplified example

```
library(foreach)

w <- Matrix::Matrix()
```

You can see the first four values are incorrectly `NULL`.

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

null_dist <- foreach::foreach(i = seq_len(6)) %dopar% {
  nrow(w)
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)

null_dist
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 1
```

Adding `.packages = "Matrix"` solves this problem.

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

null_dist <- foreach::foreach(i = seq_len(6), .packages = "Matrix") %dopar% {
  nrow(w)
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)

null_dist
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 1
```